# SASS : compare variable name within @each loop with a string

Tags: sass, each

I'm trying to find a way of comparing the variable name e.g. $topLeft within the @each loop with a string which would be for instance 'topLeft' - an example would be:

```
@mixin getCorner($topLeft:false, $topRight:false, $bottomRight:false, $bottomLeft:false) {

  @each $corner in $topLeft, $topRight, $bottomRight, $bottomLeft {

    @if #{$corner} == topLeft {

      border-top-left-radius: $corner;

    }

  }

}
```

The above obviously doesn't work, but is there a way of doing it in Sass?

Comment: Is there a practical purpose for this mixin?  Using the border-radius shorthand will be superior in any situation where all 4 values will be set, and setting 1-2 values will be almost as much typing as writing out the properties by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a variable, all the interpreter knows is the value it contains, not what its name is.  So when you're looping over your values, `$corner` is getting set to one of the values in the list.  It will never be `topLeft` unless you pass that as the value for the `$topLeft` argument, which is why your `@if` statement never evaluates to true.

If you use a default value of `null` instead of false, you can simplify a lot:

```
@mixin getCorner($topLeft: null, $topRight: null, $bottomRight: null, $bottomLeft: null) {
    border-top-left-radius: $topLeft;
    border-top-right-radius: $topRight;
    border-bottom-right-radius: $bottomRight;
    border-bottom-left-radius: $bottomLeft;
}

.foo {
    @include getCorner($topLeft: 50%, $bottomRight: 50%);
}
```

Output:

```
.foo {
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use the name `top-left` instead of `topLeft`, you can reduce the amount of code you have to write. 
Here I have a list which does not do EXACTLY what you want, but you can easily use this to go ahead and do the comparison you want to do.

```
$corners: (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right);
@mixin getCorner($cornerName, $cornerVal) {
$max: length($corners);
  @for $i from 1 through $max {
    $temp: nth($corners, $i);
    @if ($temp == $cornerName) {
      border-#{$temp}-radius: $cornerVal;
    }
  }
}

body {
@include getCorner(top-left, 2px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vinay - although it's not quite what I need.

Comment: If you could post a more extensive version of what you are trying to do, we can look into it together